# How to remove cursor from the typewriter text animation

Tags: css

I am trying to remove a cursor from the typewriter animation. I found this code online, works exactly what I wanted it to work, but I am not able to remove the cursor. What am I missing?
Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background  :#3d6485;
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 36px;
  }
.type {
  --n                     : 56;
  color                   : #000;
  opacity                 : 0;
  background              : linear-gradient(-90deg, #F3933F 5px, #0000 0) 10px 0
                          , linear-gradient(#F3933F 0 0) 0 0;
  background-size         : calc( var(--n) * 1ch ) 200%;
  -webkit-background-clip : padding-box, text;
  background-clip         : padding-box, text;
  background-repeat       : no-repeat;
  animation               : d 2s forwards
                          , b .1s infinite steps(1)
                          , t calc( var(--n) * .1s ) steps( var(--n) ) forwards;
  animation-delay         : 2s;
  }
@keyframes d {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
  }
@keyframes t {
  from { background-size: 0 200%; }
  }
@keyframes b {
  100% { background-position: 0 -100%, 0 0; }
  }
```

```html
<p class="lol">
  <span class="type">
    Hello world
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: (Try to include a [example], in this case as a stack snippet.) (also where did you find the code? They may require citing the source)

Comment: simply replace `background  : transparent;` into `.type {....}`

Comment: there were css errors in his code, I corrected them in your post

Comment: If you get rid of the cursor you have almost no effect at all - is that what you want? If so then the cursor can be made transparent by replacing #F3933F in the linear-gradients with transparent so all the timings etc remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this css is specifically for the cursor:

```css
@keyframes d {
      from{
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100%{
        opacity: 1;
            
  }
```

it looks like this is the culprit. This sets the opacity of something from 0 to 1 every 2 seconds. change it to this:

```css
@keyframes d {
      from{
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100%{
        opacity: 0;
            
  }
```

This css animation is actually entirely useless if you don't want the cursor at all. But it seems like you just "want it to work" so that might do the trick.

Comment: Glad you commented, I tried other typewriter animation effects but the issue is the character length of the paragraph is not static so setting custom width didn't work for me. Any suggestion?

Comment: @PsycheP is this an unrelated question to the cursor? I'd need more details...

Comment: there were css errors in his code, I corrected them in his post